# custom placeholder for textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

hello guys im having a problem regarding custom placeholder for my textarea 
this is my code

http://goo.gl/rIqtns
jsfiddle link

scenario is that i have a content div holds textarea and div placeholder what i want is that if textarea is null and not focus placeholder is visible but if textarea is not null and focus placeholder will be not visible and textarea is focus... i need a pure javascript function or css style that will run to ie8.

Comment: +1 for taking the pain to make a custom textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try @JamieRead solution. But for older browsers, here's the solution, PS. this works for both, old and new browsers:

Add this to your head section:

```
<script>
    function unsetPlaceholder(textarea){
        if (textarea.value=='placeholdertext'){textarea.value='';};return false;
    }

    function setPlaceholder(textarea){
        if (textarea.value==''){textarea.value='placeholdertext';return false;}
    }
</script>
```

And this to your main body:

```
<textarea onfocus="unsetPlaceholder(this)"  onblur="setPlaceholder(this)">placeholdertext</textarea>
```

yes, replace all the occurances of 'placeholdertext' with your place holder..

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rj3Zc/1/)

Comment: For a simple and faster solution this is the best approach, however if you are going to use this into more than one ```textarea```, then better wrap the code into a function or use a plugin as listed by dudes bellow.

Comment: @Kazzkiq advice implemented :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Fix for All Browsers:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Fill me …">
```

Javascript:

```
$('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
    input.val('');
    input.removeClass('placeholder');
  }
}).blur(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
    input.addClass('placeholder');
    input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
  }
}).blur();
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/u3gTL/**

Comment: I would use caution with this as if the placeholder is used on an input type of password then the placeholder text would be masked, making it look as though the password is pre filled.

Comment: in theory, this is same as my answer, except that you are using the jQuery library..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTML5 placeholder attribute `placeholder="text"`.

HTML:

```
 <textarea placeholder="text"></textarea>
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JKL2D/).

You can use the [placeholder.js library](https://github.com/NV/placeholder.js/) with this as suggested by @asavchenko.

Answer (score 0):

You can use placeholder.js library: https://github.com/NV/placeholder.js/
Works for IE>6

UPDATE: pure HTML attribute placeholder is HTML5 attribute and doesn't works in old browsers
...

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction with using the HTML5 placeholder attribute as suggested I would also recommend using https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder as a polyfill as the previously suggested https://github.com/NV/placeholder.js/ is no longer maintained.